# Django Model: How should I enforce Nth foreign key members are unique for each class instance?

Tags: python, django, model

Django Model: How should I enforce Nth foreign key members are unique for each class instance?

Say I have this model

```
class SomeClassA(models.Model):
    first = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=False)
    last = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=False)
    classChoice1 = models.ForeignKey(SomeClassB, related_name='choice1')
    classChoice2 = models.ForeignKey(SomeClassB, related_name='choice2')
    classChoice3 = models.ForeignKey(SomeClassB, related_name='choice3')
```

What is the correct way to enforce / check that the three "classChoice#" choices are unique per
 instance of SomeClassA?

In other words how do I prevent a entry from being made if any of the options selected for classChoice1, classChoice2, classChoice3 are not unique, among themselves?

In pseudo

```
classChoice1 != classChoice2
classChoice2 != classChoice3
classChoice3 != classChoice1
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [unique_together from django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

Comment: This does not answer my question. Using `        unique_together = (("classChoice1, "classChoice2", "classChoice3"),)`  allows me to create only **one instance** of SomeClassA with only one unique setting among the entire set of  SomeClassA.  I am seeking a solution where choices 1-3 of Nth SomeClassB **are unique for each instance of SomeClassA**

Answer (score 0):

To perform a such custom validation you can use [clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method. You can use it to automatically provide a value for a field, or to do *validation that requires access to more than a single field* which is you case. You can do as follow:

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models

class SomeClassA(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        if len(set((classChoice1.id, classChoice2.id, classChoice3.id))) < 3:
            raise ValidationError('classChoice[1,2,3] should have different values')
```